# My django application is not working in customdomain

Tags: django, heroku

I recently finished my django project and deployed it successfully without any errors in heroku. It works fine with the `appname.herokuapp.com` domain. But when i tried to add my custom domain, i got a very different problem.

Only my machine can access the page. Weird right! Yes. The page can be accessed only by me in my machine. But i get `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` error. Really weird! I guess this is not the problem with the code and i know i'm missing somewhere in the dns configuration. I bought my domain in big rock. So please guide me through this weird problem.

The development site is arr-coaching.herokuapp.com
The deployed site is www.arccphysics.in (Which you cannot access) :(

And any device connected to my WIFI can open the site. Some serious thing! Please help me out !

Comment: Can you show us your configuration ?

Comment: I added `www.arccphysics.in` and `arccphysics.in` in my domains in heroku. It provided with 2 dns targets which i pasted in the dns configuration in the big rock cPanel. Am i missing somewhere with the `CNAME`?